# Node based editing

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there any libraries for .net that will do node based editing like Posers shader nodes.
I would like to display a class and allow users to create custom formulas by dragging properties from 1 class to to seed the other class or other class properties.

Regards

See an example here [link text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1a9888353.png)

Comment: That link doesn't work for me. Could you clarify your question some? For instance, are you talking about graphics, or what? What area of CS is this?

Comment: Yes a graphics
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f1a9888353.png
I found another example here last image on page
http://vexiphne.net/blog/poser/

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen there isn't anything currently that does what you want. In VB 6 there was a property bag control that could do some of the functionality that you are looking for, but that is gone in .Net

You might be able to roll your own control that performs like a property bag or you could try this one ([PropertyBag in VB .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/PropertyBag_in_VB.NET.aspx)). I haven't tried it myself, but it might do what you want.